# AVFoundation Delegates

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to play different sound files and want to get notified, when one of these sound files is finished playing. So I integrated the delegate method:

```
extension ViewController: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

        if (player.url!.isEqual(self.sndAlgo1)) {
            self.audioController.audioPlayer!.stop()
            self.lblInstruction.text = "Alarmieren Sie den Notruf"
        }

        if (player.url!.isEqual(self.sndNotruf)) {
            self.audioController.audioPlayer!.stop()
            self.lblInstruction.text = "Notruf wurde abgesetzt"
        }
    }
}
```

To call the soundfiles I created a property for each of them:

```
var sndAlgo1 = NSURL(string: "")!
var sndAlgo2 = NSURL(string: "")!
var sndNotruf = NSURL(string: "")!

func initializeSounds() {
    self.sndAlgo1 = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Algo1", type: "mp3")
    self.sndAlgo2 = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Algo2", type: "mp3")
    self.sndNotruf = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Notruf", type: "mp3")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.audioController.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    self.audioController.startAudioPlayerWithURL(self.sndAlgo1)
}

@IBAction func btnEmergencyPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.lblInstruction.text = "Bitte warten"
    self.audioController.startAudioPlayerWithURL(self.sndNotruf)
}
```

the sounds are playing correctly, but the delegate method is only called once. I would have guessed it is called after every time using the player. Did I use the method in a wrong way?

Best

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your method startAudioPlayerWithURL creates an new instance of AVAudioPlayer.

Everytime you create an new instance, you need to set the delegate of the AVPlayer.

Your code will looks like this:

```
var sndAlgo1 = NSURL(string: "")!
var sndAlgo2 = NSURL(string: "")!
var sndNotruf = NSURL(string: "")!

func initializeSounds() {
    self.sndAlgo1 = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Algo1", type: "mp3")
    self.sndAlgo2 = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Algo2", type: "mp3")
    self.sndNotruf = self.audioController.createAudioFilePath("Notruf", type: "mp3")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.audioController.startAudioPlayerWithURL(self.sndAlgo1)
    self.audioController.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func btnEmergencyPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.lblInstruction.text = "Bitte warten"
    self.audioController.startAudioPlayerWithURL(self.sndNotruf)
    self.audioController.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
}
```

I'm not sure if it works, because I don't know what your method `startAudioPlayerWithURL`does.

To improve your code you can give the delegate to the `audioController` and reuse it every time you call `startAudioPlayerWithURL`